# How to find the address and port of the rank0 machine in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, pytorch, distributed-computing

I am trying to do distributed training with single node and multi-gpu config on GCP. I have set the IP address of my instance where I have my code and data. I am getting this error. Am I missing something here? Any solutions? More here https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-with-distributed-package-using-nccl-or-gloo-backend/30992/3. I would like to find the ip address of the rank0 machine.

> > File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/distributed/distributed_c10d.py", line 400, in init_process_group
> >         store, rank, world_size = next(rendezvous(url))
> >       File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/distributed/rendezvous.py", line 143, in _env_rendezvous_handler
> >         store = TCPStore(master_addr, master_port, world_size, start_daemon)
> >     RuntimeError: Connection timed out

Comment: can you provide more information about your setup? Are you using a GKE cluster as per your question tag? or using a single GCE VM with multiple GPUs?

Comment: a single GCE VM with multiple GPUs, thanks, I edited the tags.

Comment: Please provide more info about your setup - your question is very broad; 
- is the machine you're running pytorch on the same as rank0 ?; 
- are they both VM's in GCE ? 
- are they in the same VPC network ?
- did you check firewall rules for the VPC you'r VM is (VM's are) ?

For me this seems like a connectivity issue so please provide as much detail as you can.